# Getting reference error when trying to access variable from different file

Tags: javascript, dom, scope, environment-variables

There are two files `file1.js` & `file2.js`, `file1.js` is loaded in the DOM before `file2.js` that is how script tags in the body element are arranged.
Suppose there is a variable named `addressBar` in `file1` which is getting used in other JS files which are getting loaded after `file1`, whichever variables declared first are loaded first in the DOM and the later loaded files can use these variables.
But if I am using `addressBar` in the later loaded files, the editor shows a hint stating `Could not find name addressBar. Did you mean 'address'?`.

While I also checked if the `<input>` element was getting accessed and its value is being read or not, but no issue there, it is working fine.

```
window.onload = function() {
  console.log(addressBar.value);
}
```

Summarizing the sequence:

1. index.html:

```
<body>
    <input type="text" class="address-bar" />

    <script src="./grid.js"></script>
    <script src="./formula.js"></script>
</body>
```

2. grid.js: `let addressBar = document.querySelector('.address-bar');`
3. formula.js:

```
function addChildToParent(formula) {
  let childAddress = addressBar.value;

  // and so on...
}
```

Please suggest how can I not see the error `Could not find name addressBar. Did you mean 'address'?` in the editor even though `addressBar` was defined in `grid.js` which loads before `formula.js`.

Comment: Separate files have separate scoping and don't share variables (in modern JS where not everything is part of the window), you need to export/import them from different files. This is **extra** true if you use `let`, which is even finer scoped and does not hoist to the window.